# How does Android system install wearable apps

Tags: android, wear-os

As known that the Android system manages the installs on Android wearable devices.
What we need to do is pack the wearable app in the handheld app, and Android will open the pack and install the wearable app on connected wearable devices.

The question is how does Android do this distribution? I think it may be related to gms service which is used to communicate between devices. Is there any code reflecting such automated install/distribution in AOSP?

Thanks.

Comment: It works with Android ID and Kernal info... Along with your Gmail..

Comment: It is not part of AOSP.

Comment: @Don'tBenegative So, it is not pushed from phone to the wearable?

Comment: @AliNaddaf Do you know how exactly it works?

Comment: It is pushed from Phone to your wear device; there are components on your phone that unpacks the apk and extracts the wear apk and then in a coordinated effort with the corresponding framework components on the watch, verifies that it has the right signature, keys, version, etc. and then copies it over and installs that. Details of this process is not public.